# Can't I define aliases (using `export`) that are in my current directory? Doing so gives a `not found` message

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, directory, alias

**TLDR**: have to define an alias/variable using the `export` command, I can't use the full path and using a relative path (i.e. defining the alias while in the directory directly above what I want to assign) gives a `Not found` error. Anything else I can do?

I have to run these two commands:

`export FREESURFER_HOME=/usr/local/freesurfer`

`source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh`

Except the system is not my own, so I don't have permission to `/usr/local/freesurfer` . So I improvised and installed the program called freesurfer elsewhere (the full install path is `/Raid6/users/bob/Downloads/freesurfer`).

So I've been trying to set the alias `FREESURFER_HOME` to the freesurfer directory (I need to do this step because the `SetUpFreeSurfer.sh` file assumes its defined and uses it.

When I use the full path like so: `export FREESURFER_HOME=/Raid6/users/bob/Downloads/freesurfer` and then type `$FREESURFER_HOME` and press enter, I get a "Permission denied" error.

So I navigated to my Downloads directory such that typing `ls` would list, among other things, the `freesurfer` directory. And then I try `export FREESURFER_HOME=freesurfer`, but after I do that typing `$FREESURFER_HOME` and pressing enter gives me the message `freesurfer: not found`.

Not sure what to do/try from here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: `FREESURFER_HOME` is a shell variable here, not an alias.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Apologies for that and thank you for the correction! Looking into it, it seems that alises are different names for commands, while shell variables are different names for directories (or string in general?)

Comment: In your second-last paragraph, you tried to to execute “freesurfer” using the variable name. Did you check if the script/binary it points to is executable?  I have seen a number of times when you download something from the Internet and simply store it, it may not have the executable permissions.  Also, for your /Raid6 path you provide two directories assuming two different users. Are you able to log on as either of them?

Comment: And finally: in the last paragraph you try to run “freesurfer” without a path.  If the location of this executable is not part of the `PATH` variable, you would need to provide the path to the executable (to the very least `./` assuming you are in the same directory when trying to run it).

Comment: @Phoenix Thank you very much for the help! The different paths was a typo actually (accidentally copied the wrong user's path as they're all in the same parent directory), fixed it now. I did try to execute freesurfer, but you're right: that's maybe not what I'm meant to do. All I have to do is successfully run `source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh`; that's my only goal. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: @JamesRonald if `SetUpFreeSurfer.sh` is also located inside the "/Raid6/.../freesurfer" path, you shall be able to source it.  For the purpose of sourcing, a bash-containing file does not even need to be executable.  Only if you try to run it directly.  Since I do not know what this package of yours does, I also have no clue what else it requires.  I mention this as you stated that the system you are trying to run it on is beyond your own control and may lack some dependencies.  Other than that, all seems to be right according to your question and comments.

Comment: @JamesRonald, also keep in mind that `export variable="content"` does not give you any feedback with the exception of an incorrect syntax.  The same goes for `source /path/to/bash-file` unless the sourced file holds lines which print something (e.g. echo).  Typically sourcing is done so that you can run certain functions contained in the sourced file thereafter and it is not so common to actually run a script that way.  Though it is possible.

Comment: @Phoenix Sincere thanks for the continued help. So what you're saying is that, according to what I've described, `source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh` should work as expected (it should indeed run the script SetUpFreeSurfer.sh)? By the way, freesurfer is a MRI visualization program: https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/ (only if you're interested)

Comment: @Phoenix Is it possible to define environment variables without using an absolute path? For example, if my directory has a directory called `NameyName`, will running `export name=/NameyName` correctly make a variable that leads to the NameyName folder as desired? Or do I *have* to give the absolute path to NameyName all the way from the root for the export command to work?

Comment: @JamesRonald the difference between running a script directly or sourcing it is that with the latter you practically do not run the script, but its contents instead. The result is, however, mostly the same.  I’d recommend to read a bit about sourcing as this would expand this question beyond its boundaries.  A variable, like your `FREESURFER_HOME` is just that: a space holder containing a value. So, in essence you can put whatever you like in there.  In your case it appears that you would like to run the content of the variable from the command-line and that means that it needs to be found.

Comment: ... The value of your variable needs to have a full or relative path to your executable, which must exist for it to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

I leave everthing away, even the export *directive*.

`FREESURFER_HOME=freesurfer`

In other languages, this would just be `$FREESURFER_HOME = "freesurfer"`, a string assigment. In bash you decide at each use whether you mean string or value of variable

```
$  echo FREESURFER_HOME
FREESURFER_HOME

$  echo $FREESURFER_HOME
freesurfer
```

The dollar sign is the way to tell bash you mean the value/contents of that name.

After setting your variable, you can use it (with dollar sign)

`source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh` is what you want that variable for. You want to run/source a certain script in your modified fs-home directory. For one call it is exactly like `source freesurfer/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh`, if "freesurfer" is the contents.

If you type `$FREESURFER_HOME` as a command (first word is the command!), it gets expanded to its value "freesurf" (or whatever is the value), and that is not a existing command (-> not found).

In other situations, bad things have happened with valid commands in variables.

```
$  cmd='echo hello'
$  $cmd
hello
```

Nothing happenes here, it is a friendly command -- but this kind of *aliasing* is questionable, at least. I think nobody does it, it would be *disruptive*. For a normal **alias** there is an extra built-in:

```
$  alias cmd='echo hello'
$  cmd
hello
```

(Here no `$` sign -- much better!)

---

(The export might be needed to propagate the variable. Does not change these facts at all. Put it back!)

Comment: The user seems to be _using_ their variable correctly. Their issue seem to be more about where their files etc. are actually installed.

Comment: @Kusalananda "typing $FREESURFER_HOME and pressing enter gives me the message freesurfer: not found" **He is trying to use a variable as alias** (see title also)

Comment: Yes, the confusion between aliases and using variables is also an issue. Understanding when to use `$` on variable names, and when not to, is however not an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I believe I have boiled my confusion down to one question: do we *have* to use absolute paths when using the export command? For example, if my directory has a directory called `NameyName`, will running `export name=/NameyName` correctly make a variable that leads to the NameyName folder as desired? Or do I *have* to give the absolute path to `NameyName` all the way from the root for the export command to work?

Comment: @JamesRonald You have to assign it the way it will be used. The docs should say, often it is clear form context. Your $name has NameyName at the top level, with that slash, probably not "your" directory. With `name=$HOME/NameyName` you define it relative to your homedir, like `/home/james/NameyName`. With `name=NameyName` you assume it will be interpreted correctly. Sometimes exactly these things get mixed up, and a config file is not found. So don't make it worse!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose an easier option would just to make a symlink pointing to the freesurfer directory with ln -s /usr/local/freesurfer freesurfer
.